# system/console/configMgr not available in AEM

Tags: aem

I've recently changed admin credentials for OSGi console. And after that I am not able to access it. The credentials are correct as it allow me to access /system/console/bundles, only the ../configMgr is not working. Could someone please help?

Comment: what AEM version are you using? 6.2 allows for two different passwords as outlined in the documentation - https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/security-checklist.html

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting:
1. Try changing admin password again and check the error.log for any error.
2. After changing the password, try "localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr" and check for the error on browser as well as error.log.

Reference Link for Resetting Admin Password:- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__0fxc-dear_all_wehave.html **(Read all comments)**

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni